# Libxml2 installation onto Mac

Tags: python, macos, libxml2

I'm trying to install "libxml2" and "libxslt" in order to use scrapy (web scraping with python) on a mac.

I have homebrew and I ran 
`$ brew install libxml2 libxslt`

I get this message 
`OS X already provides this software and installing another version in parallel can cause all kinds of trouble.`

When I try to instal scrapy, using 
`$ pip install scrapy`

I get this error:

```
Could not find function xmlCheckVersion in library libxml2. Is libxml2 installed?
    Perhaps try: xcode-select --install
```

When I try
`$ xcode-select libxml2 install`
I get an invalid argument error.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should run `$ xcode-select --install`. This will install the XCode command line tools which include libxml2.